# GCC does not detect library path in MacOS Mojave

Tags: macos, gcc, boost, macos-mojave

I have just upgraded to MacOS Mojave and installed g++ 8 (as `g++-8`), along with the `boost` library (`libboost-dev` in linux).

Unfortunately, the g++ compiler cannot detect the boost library:

```
fatal error: boost/algorithm/string/predicate.hpp: No such file or directory
 #include <boost/algorithm/string/predicate.hpp>
```

I searched for the boost library header and found it in this path:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.67.0_1/include/boost/algorithm/string/predicate.hpp
```

However, I cannot make the compiler recognize the headers by adding this directory to `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`:

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.67.0_1/include/
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/Cellar
```

None of the commands above work, and I still get the error.

**Notes**:

- The code already gets compiled with g++ (which is Apple's LLVM), but not
  in g++-8 (GCC).
- The code used to be compiled in MacOS High Sierra, with
  g++-7. This happened after upgrading and re-installing `g++-8` and `boost`.